# imshow defaults to inverted y axis, can't be flipped using invert_yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Whenever I generate a graph in matplotlib, the axis seems to be inverted. As an example, I created a figure from an array of 0s:

```
dims = [100,100] 

square = np.zeros(dims)
plt.imshow(square)
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

Whilst doing:

```
dims = [100,100] 
square = np.zeros(dims)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.imshow(square)
```

produces the exact same figure.

How can I make it so my y-axis starts at 0 at the origin?

Comment: Do it after the plot.

Comment: The imshow function defaults to putting the origin at the top left of the Axes. You could do `invert_axes` after imshow, or alternatively just tell imshow where you want the origin to be, with `plt.imshow(square, origin='lower')`

Answer (score 1):

I think `invert_yaxis` doesn't work because in your case `Axes` are empty:

```
plt.gca()
# > <Axes: >
```

You can set axis manually instead:

```
dims = [100,100] 
square = np.zeros(dims)
plt.gca().set_xlim([0, dims[0]])
plt.gca().set_ylim([0, dims[1]])
plt.imshow(square)
```

[image]